# Syntax help in SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, syntax

Does Oracle have any builtin SQL syntax help.

I find I may have forgotten a few statements and sometimes have no Internet access.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: You can download Oracle SQL Reference. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm. Can download as PDF.

Comment: not SQL*Plus, but SQLcl can do that, ctrl+space to get next expected  possible keywords

Answer (score 1):

**No**

You can get a list of reserved words by typing `help reserved words`, but that's about it.